# Nested relationships for normalized db structure in FuelPHP ORM

Tags: orm, nested, relationship, fuelphp

First up, sorry for the mega-posting of code but...

I have the following DB structure (not my choice):

```
+---------+    +--------------+    +--------+
|  users  |    | users_groups |    | groups |
+---------+    +--------------+    +--------+
|   id    |    |   user_id    |    |   id   |
|  name   |    |   group_id   |    |  name  |
+---------+    +--------------+    +--------+
```

I've created a relationship with FuelPHP's ORM:

```
class Model_User extends Orm\Model
{
    protected static $_properties = array(
        'id',
        'name',
    );

    protected static $_has_many = array('usergroup');
}

class Model_Usergroup extends Orm\Model
{
    protected static $_table_name = 'users_groups';

    protected static $_properties = array(
        'user_id',
        'group_id',
    );

    protected static $_belongs_to = array('user', 'group');
}

class Model_Group extends Orm\Model
{
    protected static $_properties = array(
        'id',
        'name',
    );

    protected static $_has_many = array('usergroup');
}
```

And I'm now trying to get a query to display all the data from the 3 tables using the following:

```
$data['users'] = Model_User::find()
    ->related('usergroup')
    ->related('usergroup.group')
    ->get();
```

It's returning this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Model_User Object
        (
            [_is_new:Orm\Model:private] => 
            [_frozen:Orm\Model:private] => 
            [_data:Orm\Model:private] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => somename
                )

            [_original:Orm\Model:private] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => somename
                )

            [_data_relations:Orm\Model:private] => Array
                (
                    [usergroup] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [_original_relations:Orm\Model:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_view:Orm\Model:private] => 
            [_iterable:protected] => Array
                (
                )
        )
)
```

So it's starting to find the users_groups but stops? Am I even getting at this in the right way? Of course I could get this with a regular query with joins, but it would be ace to actually know how to do this with the ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gaaaak! It was just missing a PK on the users_groups table...

```
class Model_Usergroup extends Orm\Model
{
    protected static $_table_name = 'users_groups';
    protected static $_primary_key = array('pk_id');

    protected static $_properties = array(
        'pk_id',
        'user_id',
        'group_id',
    );

    protected static $_belongs_to = array('user', 'group');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a many-many relation, check the docs to see how this can be configured.

The solution you chose is only usefull when you need additional attributes saved with the relation in the users_groups table.

Comment: It's the Sentry authentication package that uses the structure, and your ORM doesn't like it at all. Just adding a specifically named PK solved it all though.

Comment: All tables used by the ORM are required to have a PK, and you are not allowed to use a FK as a PK. So if this is the table layout defined by Sentry, then they did it wrong (as in: in a non-FuelPHP compatible way).